Tension in chain/rope over wedge
Edit:
How is it possible to show that the tension in a rope passing over an edge/corner is constant?

There is a great variety of problems in engineering mechanics involving chains/ropes passing over corners/wedges and so on. Some illustrative examples are as follow:


Questions about equilibrium, involving or not friction, or velocities, accelerations and so on often involve a great diversity of solutions to the problems.
Independently of the question, however, you should always be able to solve the question using Newton 2nd law (for dynamics problems, or $a=0$ for equilibrium problems) and, to do that, one must draw free-body diagrams.
One such specific example is for the first figure, where the free-body diagram reads:

The question is about the tension in the rope passing around the corner. Why is it the same? This is a reasonable assumption, but how can one show that even though there is a slope discontinuity on the rope passing over a corner (not a smooth transition, such as ropes passing around a pulley), the tension remains constant.
My reasoning is to treat it as a "small enough pulley", such as the following FBD:

i.e., consider a differential length $dl$ of the rope passing over the corner, with a (sufficiently small) radius $r$ that approximates the corner. By summing moments about the center of the radius, one shows the tensions are equal. If the length $dl$ is small enough, friction can be neglected and the inertia of the rope portion over the corner is also negligible. So, independently of the type of problem (statics or dynamics, involving or not friction), the tension at this point on both portions of the cut rope is the same ($T_1=T_2=T$).
Is this line of though reasonable?
Clearly, this relies on the fact that a presumably small radius of curvature will exist as the rope/chain passes over a corner.
Can this be shown for a perfect corner (here assuming a 90° angle, but the angle of both surfaces can be any angle $\theta$), with a discontinuous slope?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Edited the question, with the specific question about this problem. The question is about showing the tension in the rope passing over a corner is constant. How does one show it?

Yes your reasoning is correct. More formally, assimilating the rope as a parametric curve $r(s)$, mechanical equilibrium on a portion of rope gives you:
$$
[Tt]+F = 0
$$
with $t$ the tangent vector:
$$
t = \frac{dr/ds}{\|dr/ds\|}
$$
$F$ the total external force applied on the portion and the bracket indicates you are taking the difference of the extremities. For an infinitesimal portion, you get by derivation:
$$
\frac{d}{ds}(Tt)+f = 0
$$
wit $f$ the force per unit $s$. Projecting in the tangent direction:
$$
\frac{dT}{ds} = -f\cdot t
$$
Indeed, the key property is the Frenet equation:
$$
\frac{dt}{ds} = \kappa n
$$
with $n$ the normal vector and $\kappa$ the curvature. Thus $n\cdot t = 0$. This key property is true for infinitesimal portions.
Thus, if the applies force is always normal, the tension is constant. This is the case when there is no friction and only the normal reaction force.
It is not true that taking a small increment will make the friction negligible. Yes, the total force of the friction goes to zero, but will be typically linear in $ds$. You will therefore not be able to conclude that the derivative of tension is zero. This is the reason why for the capstan equation you do get a change of tension due to friction.
The same holds for inertia. If your rope is accelerating then you have a RHS:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}(Tt)+f = \rho\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial t^2}
$$
with $\rho$ the mass density per unit $s$. If your rope has tangential acceleration, tension will not be conserved. This is why for example why the bottom of a slinky does not move even if you let go of its top.
Thus, under these assumptions (normal force and acceleration), no matter the shape of the wedge, the tension is constant. Sending the radius of curvature to zero, for an ideal corner as well, the tension is preserved.
